# Why some part of the pop up is cut off

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following HTML/CSS:

```
<div id="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Add Item to Your Shopping Cart</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="copy">
            <label>Item:</label>
            <select id="itemChoice">
                <option value="Wine" selected>Wine</option>
                <option value="Shot">Shot</option>
                <option value="Beer">Beer</option>
            </select>
            <br /><span id="spanPrice" />
            TESTING

        <label>Quantity:</label>
        <input type="text" id="rname" name="email" placeholder="Jane Doe">

        <label>Price:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="contact" placeholder="name@email.com">

        </div>
        <div class="cf footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<a href="#modal" class="btn go">Activate Modal</a>

/* Normal styles for the modal */
#modal {
    left:50%;
    margin:-250px 0 0 -40%;
    opacity: 0;
    position:absolute;
    top:-50%;
    visibility: hidden;
    width:80%;
    box-shadow:0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    box-sizing:border-box;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
    /* Make the modal appear when targeted */
    #modal:target {
        opacity: 1;
        top:50%;
        visibility: visible;
    }
#modal .header,#modal .footer {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
    #modal .footer {
        border:none;
        border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
        border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    }
#modal h2 {
    margin:0;
}
#modal .btn {
    float:right;
}
#modal .copy,#modal .header, #modal .footer {
    padding:15px;
}
.modal-content {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#modal .copy {
    background: #fff;
}

#modal .overlay {
    background-color: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

why does the pop up cut off the rest of the tags:

[image]

Pop up style:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans);
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab);
        * {

        /*with these codes padding and border does not increase it's width.Gives intuitive style.*/

        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;

        }
        div#envelope{
        width:100%;
        margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
        background-color:#f2f4fb;
        padding:10px 0;
        border:1px solid gray;
        border-radius:5px;
        }

        form{
        width:70%;
        margin:0 15%;
        }

        form header {
        text-align:center;
        font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
        }

        /* Makes responsive fields.Sets size and field alignment.*/
        input[type=text], #itemChoice{
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width:100%;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius:5px;
        border:1px solid #7ac9b7;
        }

        #additem
        {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width:100%;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius:5px;
        border:1px solid #7ac9b7;
        background-color:rgb(164, 230, 219);
        }
        #addToTable
        {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width:50%;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius:5px;
        border:1px solid #7ac9b7;
            background-color:rgb(164, 230, 219);
        }
        #cancelAdd {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            width:50%;
            padding: 15px;
            border-radius:5px;
            border:1px solid #B0B8B6;
        background-color:#BBCBC8;
        }
        textarea{
        width:100%;
        padding: 15px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        border:1px solid #7ac9b7;
        border-radius:5px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        resize:none;
        }

        input[type=text]:focus,
        textarea:focus {
        border-color: #4697e4;
        }

        /* By using @ media form can have different layout for screen, mobile phone, tablet.*/

        /* Sets the form layout for mobile phone, tablet*/
        @media screen and (max-device-width: 600px){

        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans);
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab);
        * {

        /*with these codes padding and border does not increase it's width.Gives intuitive style.*/

        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;

        }
        div#envelope{
        width:50%;
        margin: 10px 30% 10px 25%;
        background-color:#f2f4fb;
        padding:10px 0;
        border:1px solid gray;
        border-radius:10px;
        }

        form{
        width:70%;
        margin:0 15%;
        }

        form header {
        text-align:center;
        font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
        }

        /* Makes responsive fields.Sets size and field alignment.*/
        input[type=text], #itemChoice{
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width:100%;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius:5px;
        border:1px solid #7ac9b7;
        }

        #additem
        {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width:100%;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius:5px;
        border:1px solid #7ac9b7;
        background-color:rgb(164, 230, 219);
        }
        #addToTable
        {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width:50%;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius:5px;
        border:1px solid #7ac9b7;
            background-color:rgb(164, 230, 219);
        }
        #cancelAdd {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            width:50%;
            padding: 15px;
            border-radius:5px;

            border:1px solid #B0B8B6;
        background-color:#BBCBC8;
        }
        textarea{
        width:100%;
        padding: 15px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        border:1px solid #7ac9b7;
        border-radius:5px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        resize:none;
        }

        input[type=text]:focus,
        textarea:focus {
        border-color: #4697e4;
        }
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the styles for your drop down, etc which are used inside the modal?

Comment: I tried the code in my Chrome browser using http://htmledit.squarefree.com/.  Seems to work fine.  Which browser are you using?

Comment: Can you try running this gist (https://gist.github.com/vivganes/3046767038a5ec9128b9) in chrome and tell me how it works??

Comment: That is so weird... When I run the page by itself works fine but when I copy the entire CSS to my page it gets cut off :/

Comment: Good progress then... now we know there is something else (most probably the parent of your modal) that is responsible for this behaviour.  Is it possible to share the html,css for the modal's parent?

Comment: My JQuery was giving the issue. I temp removed it and was able to see the full Popup... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code given executes perfectly.  Looks like there is a problem with something else in your page.

Particularly, take a look at the parent of your modal.  This could affect the display of your modal.

Comment: I had some JQuery which caused the issue. I have to inspect that carefully. Thank you

Comment: Whenever I add the SCRIPT tag in my page the pop up cuts off... Can you please help?

Comment: @SiKni8 then the script which you are trying to add is the culprit.  Can you share the script, if possible?

Comment: I will share entire page HTML: http://pastebin.com/LM7SFzTB (If I remove the script tag entirely it works fine but as soon as I add the JQuery code my pop up cuts out) Please let me know what you think...

Comment: Looks like some weird behaviour.  Change ```<br /><span id="spanPrice"/>``` to ```<br /><span id="spanPrice"></span>``` and it works fine.  I have always been led to think that ```<span id="spanPrice"></span>``` is equal to ```<br /><span id="spanPrice"/>```

Answer (score 0):

I can see one immediate problem which has cause me issues in the past:

Mixing units - pixels and percent - doesn't work.  You are measuring width in percent and then adding margins/padding in pixels.

The percentage values will scale and the pixels will stay as is.  The page will not scale proportionally and you should include the value, "luck" in the reason why it looks fine in some scenarios.

As long as you continue with this approach, you will have your popup 'cut off' when the zoom level changes.

Have you tried measuring in EM?  Or - the easier option - have you tried using Pure CSS or Twitter Bootstrapper?  Using either of those two packages will get you what you want.  And you wont even need a spoon to remove your eyes.  CSS development is not nice, even after 18+ years.

NB: I didn't even try this code in a IDE.